# What is the function source code of the array_length function in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

We are running an older version of Postgres for this project that does not support the array_length function. I don't have any way to update the version (not a DBA), can anyone either show me the source code or tell me how/where I can see it for myself?

EDIT: Sorry, we are using version 8.2.15

Comment: what postgres version you have? And probably is time you hire a dba, or start learning some db stuff. Update postgre to newer version isnt that hard and you will get access to lot of new fuctions.

Comment: The built-in `array_length` function will not be written in SQL. PostgreSQL source is located here: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/ .

Comment: We are using version 8.2.15, the issue isn't that its a small team who don't know what they're doing, the issue is that the project is too big and my part of it is too small to make any unilateral changes just so i can do my job easier (I think there are well over 100 people on the project). I also don't have the clout to _tell_ the dba's to do _anything_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original code of the function is in c. I don't think you want to use it.

You can try this (I'm unable to test it in your version, of course).

```
create function my_array_length(anyarray, int)
returns int language sql as $$
    select array_upper($1, $2)- array_lower($1, $2)+ 1
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this should work, 8.2 supports both array_upper and array_lower, although now I feel like i should have thought of this, its so simple. I'll test it and get back to you.